# Error importing contacts Wordpress Multisite

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I tried to import contacts on a new WordPress Multisite installation, and received the following error:

```
 "Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
 We can't load the requested web page. This page requires cookies to be 
 enabled in your browser settings. Please check this setting and enable 
 cookies (if they are not enabled). Then try again. If this error 
 persists, contact the site adminstrator for assistance.

 Site Administrators: This error may indicate that users are accessing 
 this page using a domain or URL other than the configured Base URL. 
 EXAMPLE: Base URL is http://example.org, but some users are accessing 
 the page via http://www.example.org or a domain alias like 
 http://myotherexample.org.

 Error type: Could not find a valid session key."
```

In the error log, it has the following errors:

```
    [info] $backTrace = #0 .../public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(363): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 .../public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(859): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("We can't load the requested web page. This page requires cookies to be enable...")
#2 .../public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(854): CRM_Core_Controller->invalidKeyCommon()
#3 .../public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(314): CRM_Core_Controller->invalidKey()
#4 .../public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(206): CRM_Core_Controller->key("CRM_Contact_Import_Controller", TRUE, FALSE)
#5 .../public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Import/Controller.php(45): CRM_Core_Controller->__construct("Import Contacts", "null")
#6 .../public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(307): CRM_Contact_Import_Controller->__construct("Import Contacts", TRUE, "null", NULL, "false")
#7 .../public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
#8 .../public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#9 .../public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1133): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#10 [internal function](): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke("")
#11 .../public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(496): call_user_func_array((Array:2), (Array:1))
#12 .../public_html/wp-admin/admin.php(226): do_action("toplevel_page_CiviCRM")
#13 {main}
```

(I've removed part of the directory url for security/privacy)

Does anyone have an idea of what I can try to fix this?

WordPress version: 4.2.2

CiviCRM version: 4.6

Other activated plugins:

- BackWPup
- Black Studio TinyMCE Widget
- Brute Protect
- Coming Soon Page & Maintenance Mode by SeedProd
- Disable Comments
- Redirection
- Seamless Sticky Custom Post Types
- Simple Lightbox
- Types - Complete Solution for Custom Fields and Types
- User Admin Simplifier
- WordFence Security
- WordPress MU Domain Mapping

Import file type: CSV (it's just a list of contact information.  We went through the data to remove inconsistencies)

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately that error message is to generic to be helpful. Please enable debugging & backtrace and/or get specific error messages from your server logs. Also please specify your CiviCRM version, any other plugins, and more details about what exactly you were importing.

Comment: Since this is a multi-site installation can you add some details about the multi-site:  Is this a subdirectory or subdomain multisite?   Is the plugin active on the main site or a sub site or network activated?  Are you using a domain mapping plugin?  If so which one and are you also mapping the administration and login pages?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out it was errors in the data.  I picked apart the spreadsheet and went from the ground up and it finally gave me a report of what the errors were instead of this vague error message.

The errors were:

- Country name USA instead of US
- Some of the date formats were wrong

I believe there might have also been some strange formatting in the original spreadsheet that affected the upload.